# S. Weinberg, “The Quantum theory of fields: Foundations” (1995), Eq. (9.2.12)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform

In Weinberg's book The Quantum Theory of Fields, volume 1 on p.387, there is a Fourier transform as:

$$\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=(2\pi)^{-3}\int{\mathrm{d}^3p\,e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})}E(\mathbf{p})}$$ where $E(\mathbf{p})=\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}.$

I don't know how to understand or to calculate this Fourier thanrform properly.

And Weinberg claimed that $\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ can be written in terms of a Hankel function of negative order :
$$\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\frac{m}{2\pi^2r}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r
}\big(\frac{1}{r}K_{-1}(mr)\big).$$

I am wondering what exactly $K_{-1}$ means, usually we denote Hankel function as $H$ and $K$ as the second kind of Modified Bessel functions.

Comment: Would Math.SE be a better home for this since it's really a question about computing a Fourier transform?

Comment: $K_\alpha$ can be expressed with the Hankel functions: [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1)

Comment: @RichardMyers Oh thank you for your reminder, I hope that someone knows quantum field theory could help and I will also ask this question on Math.SE.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux oh yes, I know that but I'm not sure if Weinberg means that since I don't know how to do that Fourier transform.

Comment: Show your efforts. Do the angular integrals first.

Comment: [Definition](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E8).  Show your work.

Comment: Practiced with [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Yukawa_Potential:_The_Coulomb_potential_with_mass) first?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you very much for your advice and the pages, I worked out the angular integral and compare it with 10.32.11 in this [page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E8),I got the same result, but $\nu$ can not take the value -1. Is there any problem taking $\nu$ to be -1?

Comment: Not sure. Negative indices are like their minus ones, except possibly at the origin.

Comment: I was going through the same passage and does not seem just computation. The result must include some other assumption. Just plotting both expressions they don't seem to agree even. Plus the end result is independent of any cutoff in p, from an integral that seems very divergent. Weinberg does not seem to give much details..

Comment: I believe the original thing is just divergent and although you can algebraically transform the Fourier transform into that expression with the Bessel function, the Basset Integral (10.32.11) just does not converge (hold) for negative indices.