# What type of regulation is being employed?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, regularization, ground-state

As already mentioned in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620770/). In the context of QFT, the kernel of integration for the overlap of a field configuration ket, $| \Phi \rangle$ with the vacuum $|0\rangle$ in a free theory is given by (See: S. Weinberg's Vol. 1 QFT Foundations Ch. 9.2)
$$ \mathcal{E}({\bf x},{\bf y}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int {\rm d}^3{\bf p}\, e^{i{\bf p}\cdot({\bf x}-{\bf y})}\sqrt{{\bf p}^2 + m^2}\tag{1}\label{eq:kernel}$$
which can be shown to algebraically match the following expression by abusing the [Basset Integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E11) for index $\nu = -1$.

$$\mathcal{E}({\bf x},{\bf y}) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \frac{m}{r} \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} r} \left( \frac{1}{r} K_{-1}(m r) \right)\quad \text{for}\quad |{\bf x - y}| = r \tag{2}\label{eq:kernel2},$$
where $K_{-1}$ denotes a modified Bessel function of the second kind. It is clear that the integration in Eq.~\eqref{eq:kernel} is divergent, while Eq.~\eqref{eq:kernel2} is not, so some sort of regularization happened in between these steps. Does anybody know which technique one could use to formalize the relation between the two?

Comment: $\sqrt{\boldsymbol p^2+m^2}$ is tempered so this is jut the Fourier transform of a distribution, a perfectly well-defined operation that requires no regularization. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform), to get you started.

Comment: So that means I should interpret (2) also in the sense of distributions? Meaning it only makes sense when integrated against a test function over $r$?, there is no other variable left..

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the standard Fourier transform of functions instead of distributions (see @AccidentalFourierTransform comment), you can regularize as follows,
$$\mathcal{E}({\bf x},{\bf y}, t_x,t_y) := \mathcal{E}({\bf x},{\bf y}, t,t)$$
for
$$\mathcal{E}({\bf x},{\bf y}, t_x,t_y) = w-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int {\rm d}^3{\bf p}\, e^{i[{\bf p}\cdot({\bf x}-{\bf y}) - p^0(t_x-y_y-i\epsilon)]}\sqrt{{\bf p}^2 + m^2}$$
where $p^0:= \sqrt{{\bf p}^2 + m^2}$ and $w$ denotes the *weak limit*: first integrate against a smooth compactly support (or Schwartz) function of $({\bf x},{\bf y}) \in \mathbb{R}^6$ and next take the limit. Using that procedure one sees that it is equivalent to directly integrate the smooth function against the integral kernel in the right-hand side of (2).   Hence (2) is an identity *in the sense of distributions* in ${\cal S}'(\mathbb{R}^6)$.

Comment: So I was indeed trying something of that sort, namely, a Zeta Riemann regularization where what one includes is $e^{-\epsilon x}$ for example. Since one is taking the limit in at the end, will the factor of $p^0$ play a role? Also I assume as @AccidentalFourierTransform mentions this is to hold only in the sense of distributions, right?

Comment: Yes the *positive* factor $p^0$ plays a crucial role: the integral converges just in view of it when $\epsilon>0$. The final identity is in the sense of distributions, but the manipulations at  $\epsilon>0$ are valid in the general sense of functions.

Comment: Sorry of course I mean I was using $e^{-\epsilon p }$, so my comment was directed towards the $+m^2$